# Is there a theory about functions whose results are "negative" to the results of other functions?

Tags: functions

Let's say we have a function $x \cdot 2$, which gives results:
$2,4,6,8,10,\ldots$. We can construct "negative" function $x \cdot 2-1$, which results will be: $1,3,5,7,9,\ldots$. So the all natural numbers will be a sum of both results. But could be such a "negative" function be created for $x \cdot 3$? Is there a theory which analyze it?

**Added:** One more try in explaining what do I mean:
Every function have a set of results. Those sets can be combined like any sets. Now the question is: has been invented any methods and/or theory behind them, that would allow for transforming one function into another one, based on the relation of their result sets. So in my example: I know the function $x*2$ and its result set, and I would like to find another function which set would "complete" the natural numbers. I know that would be $x*2-1$, but it's just intuition. How could I find that kind of function for $x*3$? I'm seeking for theory/methods that could guide me to the solution to those kind of problems.

Comment: The field of mathematics where things like these are studied is called *Number Theory* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_theory).

Comment: Yes but this is very broad. I'm interested in this specific problem of "inverting" functions.

Comment: This is the problem, that I'm not aware of precise word for it, but I would like to know one. I updated my question with a better explanation.

Comment: You are asking for a function whose image is the complement of that of a given function.

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to formalize your question.

Call $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ *cofinal* iff for all natural numbers $n$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $a \geq n$. Call $A$ *doubly cofinal* iff both $A$ and $A^c$ are cofinal. Whenever $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is cofinal, lets write $\underline{A} : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ for corresponding the "enumerating function."

For instance:

$$\underline{2\mathbb{N}}(n) = 2n, \qquad \underline{(2\mathbb{N})^c}(n) = 2n-1$$

Your question is essentially:

> **Question.** Is there any theory surrounding the following problem?
>
> Given a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ that is doubly cofinal, such that a simple and straightforward expression is known for the function $\underline{A},$ find a simple and straightforward expression for $\underline{A^c}.$

For instance, its clear that:

$$\underline{3\mathbb{N}}(n) = 3n$$

But you'd like to be able to write: $$\underline{(3\mathbb{N})^c}(n) = \;???$$ where the question marks are replaced by something simple and useful.

I don't know the answer to this question, but it seems like a natural and worthwhile thing to think about. +1

**Edit.** It seems possible that

$$\underline{(3\mathbb{N})^c}(n) = \mathrm{floor}\frac{n+2}{3}+\mathrm{floor}\frac{n+1}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks! I'm not a mathematician unfortunately, so my vocabulary is particularly poor, that's why I had hard time to formulate the proper question about it :) .

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda, this is a common experience. I wouldn't worry too much about it - although if you do want to be able to ask questions on the site, you'll have to learn the lingo. Most people aren't as good as me at interpreting vague questions, unfortunately :)

Comment: I consider myself pretty good at interpreting vague questions, but I don't think I could have spun this story. +1

Comment: @EricStucky, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Write $\mathbb N^+$ to denote the set of integers that are greater than zero
(the positive integers).
Suppose $f: \mathbb N^+ \to \mathbb N^+$ is an increasing function, so that it enumerates a subset of $\mathbb N^+$ in increasing order.

Write $f(\mathbb N^+)$ to denote the image of $f$. You want a function
$f^\complement: \mathbb N^+ \to \mathbb N^+$ whose image is the complement of
the image of $f$ in $\mathbb N^+$, that is,
$f^\complement(\mathbb N^+)\cup f(\mathbb N^+) = \mathbb N^+$
and $f^\complement(\mathbb N^+)\cap f(\mathbb N^+) = \emptyset$.

The set of the $f(n)$ smallest elements of $\mathbb N^+$ is the union
of the set of the $n$ smallest elements of $f(\mathbb N^+)$
(the $n$ smallest numbers you can produce by taking $f(x)$)
and the $f(n) - n$ smallest elements of $f^\complement(\mathbb N^+)$.
That is, if $f(n) > n$,
the integers $\{1,\ldots,f(n)\}$ include the integers
$\{f^\complement(1),\ldots,f^\complement(f(n)-n)\}$
but not $f^\complement(f(n)-n+1)$.
That is, $f^\complement(x) > f(n)$ if and only if $x > f(n) - n$,
that is, $x + n > f(n)$

So one way we can be sure to find out the value of $f^\complement(x)$
is to find the minimum $n$ such that $x + n \leq f(n)$.
This ensures that for this value of $n$,
$f^\complement(x) < f(n)$ 
(the definition of $f^\complement$ rules out equality)
and if $n > 1$, then $f(n - 1) < f^\complement(x)$.
For $n > 1$, then, there are exactly $n - 1$ members of
$f(\mathbb N^+)$ that are less than $f^\complement(x)$, that is, the function
$f^\complement$ "skips" $n-1$ numbers less than $f^\complement(x)$.
It follows that $f^\complement(x) = x + n - 1.$
And if $n = 1$, then $f^\complement(x) < f(1)$, no numbers are "skipped",
and $f^\complement(x) = x = x + n - 1$.

The conclusion is: if $n$ is the least integer such that $x + n \leq f(n)$,
then $f^\complement(x) = x + n - 1.$

The sentence "$n$ is the least integer such that $x + n \leq f(n)$"
can be written
$$
n = \min \{t\in\mathbb N^+ \mid x + t \leq f(t) \}
$$
and so
$$
f^\complement(x) = x + \min \{t\in\mathbb N^+ \mid x + t \leq f(t) \} - 1.
$$

This might not be the way you were hoping to write the sought-for function,
but it is actually a relatively simple formula.

A formula in the particular case $f: x \mapsto 3x$ that you might like is
$$
f^\complement(x) = \left\lfloor \frac{3x - 1}{2} \right\rfloor,
$$
where $\lfloor y\rfloor$ means the greatest integer that is not
greater than $y$.

The way I came upon this formula was to consider that in the first $3n$
positive integers, $n$ of them are in the image of $f$ and $2n$ of them
are in the image of $f^\complement$; on average, $f^\complement(x)$
must increase by $3$ for each time we add $2$ to $x$.
This gives the approximation $f^\complement(x) \approx \frac32 x$.
To make it exact, we apply $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$
(which makes all the results be integers) and "adjust" the results by 
adding or subtracting a constant term inside the brackets
so the answer comes out right. 
In particular, $\left\lfloor\frac32\cdot2\right\rfloor = 3$,
but $f^\complement(2) = 2$, indicating that we should subtract something
from $\frac32\cdot2$; but $f^\complement(1) = 1$, so the most we can
subtract is $\frac12$ (because $\frac32\cdot1 - 1 = \frac12$).
So we try $\left\lfloor\frac32 x - \frac12\right\rfloor$, simplify it to
$\left\lfloor\frac{3x - 1}{2}\right\rfloor$, 
and check that it works, which it does.

Comment: This is by-the-by, but why $\mathbb{W}$ instead of just $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @WillR Many people - myself included - consider $0$ to be a natural number. (My understanding is that this is overwhelmingly true in logic, overwhelmingly false in number theory, and mixed in other fields; but that's based purely on anecdote.)

Comment: @WillR Noah Schweber explained why not just $\mathbb N$. I'm not sure where I last saw $\mathbb W$ used--I thought it was somewhere on this page, but it is not. Would $\mathbb N^+$ be better?

Comment: I've seen $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{N}^{+}$, $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, and variations on these, but never $\mathbb{W}$. Is it common?

Comment: @WillR See http://texblog.org/2007/08/27/number-sets-prime-natural-integer-rational-real-and-complex-in-latex/ for example; but http://www.riosalado.edu/web/oer/WRKDEV100-20011_INTER_0000_v1/lessons/Mod01_VarConstantandRealNumbers.shtml defines $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb W$ more explicitly and according to that page they are the opposite from what I intended. That alone seems like a good enough reason to use $\mathbb N^+$ instead. Done!

Comment: Ooooh! For some reason I didn't think of describing them as *whole* numbers - it's just not the adjective I typically use. It makes more sense now.

Comment: Hi all. I sometimes use $\mathbb{W}$ as a convenient shorthand for $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ (because $\mathbb{N}$ for me usually means $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$). I mentioned this in the comments under the OP's question; but, I ended up deleting the comment. So that's probably where the $\mathbb{W}$'s came from.

Comment: @goblin Hey, thanks for clearing that up! Good to know I didn't just imagine it.